# Never ending While

Tags: python

In this code I try to call a function. On the other hand its not working the way I want it to work, for it is staying in the loop even though I am changing the loops condition *options_secondscenario[0]* from 0 to 1 at the end of the Loop. What I want this to do is to move to third_scenario() function. Thanks in advance.

```
options_secondscenario = ['Whats going on out there?', 'So what now?']

def third_scenario():
    print "This is the third scenario"
    choiceselection2 = raw_input("> ")
    if choiceselection2 == 1:
        print "stay"
    else:
        print "leave"

def dead():
    print "You are dead"
    exit()

def second_scenario():
    print "Conversation 1"
    print "Conversation 2"
    print "Conversation 3"
    print options_secondscenario
    choices = options_secondscenario[0]
    while choices == options_secondscenario[0]:  
        choiceselection = raw_input("> ")   
        if choiceselection == 'Whats going on out there?':
            print "Conversation 4"
        elif choiceselection == 'Whats up':
            print "Nothing"        
        elif choiceselection == 'what is that':
            print "I dont know"
        elif choiceselection == 'is':
         dead()        
        else: 
         third_scenario()
    choices == options_secondscenario[1]

second_scenario()
```

Comment: What are you comparing choices with on this line `while choices == :`? Is it a typo?

Comment: And this line: `choices == options_secondscenario[1]`. You probably meant to use assignment operator "=" instead of compare operator "=="

Comment: Fixed. Yes it was a typo when I copied, however its not the cause of the problem. When I use assigment operator here while choices = options_secondscenario[0] it gives me a synthax error tho

Comment: No your while line is ok now. Its the line after your while loop i am talking about.

Comment: You aren't modifying the `choices` variable anywhere. Of course it's an infinite loop.

Comment: But at the end of the Else, I am adding ''choices == options_secondscenario[1]'', is there something wrong with it?

Comment: 1) That line isn't inside the loop. 2) `==` is a comparison operator.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to change your `choices` var AFTER the loop (check your indentation). So the while loop never gets a chance to reach this statement.

Also, you are using the compare operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=` like so:

`choices = options_secondscenario[1]`

That line should be somewhere INSIDE your while loop. Check your indentation.